# Search string for repeating instances of a word

Tags: macos, swift

I have a string, and I want to find the locations of every user chosen word inside that string. For instance, if the user chooses "my", I want to find every time "my" is found in the string. Currently I am using:

```
var range = stringContent?.rangeOfString("my")
println(range?.location)
```

Unfortunately this only gives me the location of the first "my" in the string. How would I find the location of all the "my"s? Google has not been much help - all the suggestions and examples find the first instance of the word. I want all the instances.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, now in Swift...

```
let string: NSString = "my blah my blah my"

let searchString = "my"

var range: NSRange = string.rangeOfString(searchString)

while range.location != NSNotFound {
    println(range)

    let searchRange = NSMakeRange(range.location + range.length, string.length - range.length - range.location)

    range = string.rangeOfString(searchString, options: nil, range: searchRange)
}
```

This prints...

```
(0,2)
(8,2)
(16,2)
```

Which are the correct locations of the string "my".

Answer (score 1):

This is basically what @Fogmeister suggested, but using NSString's built in method [enumerateSubstringsInRange(_:options:usingBlock:)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/enumerateSubstringsInRange:options:usingBlock:). It will get you an array of the ranges at which "my" appears.

```
var rangesOfMatches = [NSRange]()

someString.enumerateSubstringsInRange(NSMakeRange(0, someString.length), options: .ByWords) { (substring, substringRange, _, _) in
    if substring == "my" {
        rangesOfMatches.append(substringRange)
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah. I was thinking this too. Might be very inefficient for long strings with one few occurences of the search word though.

Comment: This seems to work well - I'll try implementing this into my code. May I ask what the (substring, substringRange, _, _) is?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NSScanner` to scan up to a string, record the index, scan past the string, rinse and repeat:

```
let scanner = NSScanner(string: "This is a test.")

while !scanner.atEnd {
    scanner.scanUpToString("is", intoString: nil)
    println(scanner.scanLocation) // will print 2 the first time around, and 5 the second
    scanner.scanString("is", intoString: nil)
}
```

That should give you the start index of every instance of the string you are searching for.

Note, however that it if it is used exactly like this, it will also record the end index for the string. Discard that.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use pure Swift String and Range, you will need to do this in a loop:

```
var stringContent = "amydamydamydamydamydamydamydamydamydamydamydamyd"

var index = stringContent.startIndex

while let range = stringContent.rangeOfString("my", options: NSStringCompareOptions.allZeros, range: Range(start: index, end: stringContent.endIndex)) {
        index = range.endIndex.successor()
        println(index)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution for Swift, I find it cumbersome with subString & String.Index in Swift !!!

```
let myString = "gffffsfjjjjjjfsfffffffsjjjjfs"
let subString = "fs"

let strLen = countElements(myString)

//init search range : the whole string
var searchRange = Range(start:advance(myString.startIndex,0), end: advance(myString.startIndex, strLen))

var foundRange = myString.rangeOfString(subString, options: NSStringCompareOptions.CaseInsensitiveSearch, range: searchRange, locale: nil)

var i: Int  = 0;
while ((foundRange?.isEmpty) != nil) {
    i++

    //recaculate searchRange
    searchRange = Range(start:advance(foundRange!.endIndex ,0), end: advance(myString.startIndex, strLen))

    foundRange = myString.rangeOfString(subString, options: NSStringCompareOptions.CaseInsensitiveSearch, range: searchRange, locale: nil)
}

NSLog("Count = \(i)")
```

//Extension version

```
extension String {
    func countOccurent(_subString : String) -> Int {
        let strLen = countElements(self)

        //init search range : the whole string
        var searchRange = Range(start:advance(self.startIndex,0), end: advance(self.startIndex, strLen))

        var foundRange = self.rangeOfString(_subString, options: NSStringCompareOptions.CaseInsensitiveSearch, range: searchRange, locale: nil)

        var i: Int  = 0;
        while ((foundRange?.isEmpty) != nil) {
            i++

            //re-caculate searchRange
            searchRange = Range(start:advance(foundRange!.endIndex ,0), end: advance(self.startIndex, strLen))

            foundRange = self.rangeOfString(_subString, options: NSStringCompareOptions.CaseInsensitiveSearch, range: searchRange, locale: nil)
        }

        NSLog("Result = \(i)")

        return i
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

My swift-fu is lacking, but here's an option in Obj-C.  (I'd love to see how this translates to swift - I couldn't get the constructor for NSCountedSet to take the array..)

```
NSUInteger count = [[[NSCountedSet alloc] initWithArray: [@"hello world hello again" componentsSeparatedByString: @" "]] countForObject: @"hello"];
```