# Find index of Nth instance of substring in string in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, string, swift2

My Swift app involves searching through text in a UITextView. The user can search for a certain substring within that text view, then jump to any instance of that string in the text view (say, the third instance). I need to find out the integer value of which character they are on.

For example:

**Example 1:** The user searches for "hello" and the text view reads "hey hi hello, hey hi hello", then the user presses down arrow to view second instance. I need to know the integer value of the first `h` in the second hello (i.e. which # character that h in hello is within the text view). The integer value should be `22`.

**Example 2:** The user searches for "abc" while the text view reads "abcd" and they are looking for the first instance of `abc`, so the integer value should be `1` (which is the integer value of that `a` since it's the first character of the instance they're searching for).

How can I get the index of the character the user is searching for?

Comment: This is mostly a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28685420/search-string-for-repeating-instances-of-a-word

Comment: @rmaddy Seems helpful to me, but not quite exactly what I'm asking here. Thank you though.

Comment: The answers are exactly what you need in general. You get the 2nd substring by passing a range that starts at the end of the 1st substring.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Search string for repeating instances of a word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28685420/search-string-for-repeating-instances-of-a-word)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Xcode 11 • Swift 5 or later**

```
let sentence = "hey hi hello, hey hi hello"
let query = "hello"
var searchRange = sentence.startIndex..<sentence.endIndex
var indices: [String.Index] = []

while let range = sentence.range(of: query, options: .caseInsensitive, range: searchRange) {
    searchRange = range.upperBound..<searchRange.upperBound
    indices.append(range.lowerBound)
}

print(indices)   // "[7, 21]\n"
```

Comment: Output will be like [Swift.String.Index(_rawBits: 1), Swift.String.Index(_rawBits: 524288)]

Comment: Yes it changed somewhere in the Swift evolution process but it is correct.

Answer (score 5):

Another approach is `NSRegularExpression` which is designed to easily iterate through matches in an string. And if you use the `.ignoreMetacharacters` option, it will not apply any sophisticated wildcard/regex logic, but will just look for the string in question. So consider:

```
let string = "hey hi hello, hey hi hello"  // string to search within
let searchString = "hello"                 // string to search for
let matchToFind = 2                        // grab the second occurrence

let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: searchString, options: [.caseInsensitive, .ignoreMetacharacters])
```

You could use `enumerateMatches`:

```
var count = 0
let range = NSRange(string.startIndex ..< string.endIndex, in: string)
regex.enumerateMatches(in: string, range: range) { result, _, stop in
    count += 1
    if count == matchToFind {
        print(result!.range.location)
        stop.pointee = true
    }
}
```

Or you can just find all of them with `matches(in:range:)` and then grab the n'th one:

```
let matches = regex.matches(in: string, range: range)
if matches.count >= matchToFind {
    print(matches[matchToFind - 1].range.location)
}
```

Obviously, if you were so inclined, you could omit the `.ignoreMetacharacters` option and allow the user to perform regex searches, too (e.g. wildcards, whole word searches, start of word, etc.).

For Swift 2, see [previous revision of this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/39361684/3).